# How to get GstBuffer flags in Python

Tags: python, gstreamer

In GStreamer C API, we can use the `GST_BUFFER_FLAG_IS_SET` macro to check GstBuffer flags. This does not seem to be available in the Python bindings. How can I access these flags in Python?

I am using the Python GObject Introspection library. GStreamer version is 1.8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gst-1.0/classes/Buffer.html#Gst.Buffer.has_flags

```
 has_flags(flags)
    Parameters: flags (Gst.BufferFlags)
    Return type:    bool
```

An example:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gst

Gst.init(None)

buf = Gst.Buffer.new()
res = buf.has_flags(Gst.BufferFlags.LAST)

print(res)
```

```sh
$ python3 gst.py 
False
```

**! As figured out in the comments, this symbol was introduced in GStreamer 1.10 !**

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want, except it doesn't work for me: `AttributeError: 'Buffer' object has no attribute 'has_flags'`. Could this be a versioning issue? I do see it says Gst 1.0 at the top of the page, which should be okay.

Comment: Added an example. That one worked fine for me. GStreamer 1.16, but that particular symbol should be there for a long time..

Comment: This still gives me the attribute error on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried it on an 18.04 machine (which offers gstreamer 1.14.5) and it worked on there, so looks like a versioning issue. Pity, I need to make this work on 16.04 and without updating gstreamer beyond what apt offers.

Comment: Looks like `has_flags` has been added in 1.10: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/blob/1.14.4/gst/gstbuffer.c#L338

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer since there doesn't seem to be anything to be done in my version (I'll change the accepted answer if something better comes up). Only, could you please update your answer to reflect that it's only valid since 1.10 onward? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I have added a note about 1.10. I was just looking at the python docs. And there `get_flags()` was properly marked as being introduced by 1.10, but this note was missing for `has_flags()`. So I assumed that one would be older..